# Get method called-as str in the callee

Tags: oop, raku

I would like to introspect the tail end of a method call from the callee side.

Right now I am doing this explicitly...

```
# caller side
s.pd: '.shape';
s.pd: '.to_json("test.json")';
s.pd: '.iloc[2] = 23';

# callee side
method pd( Str $call ) {
    given $call {
        when /shape/   { ... }
        when /to_json/ { ... }
        #etc
    }
}
```

BUT, I would **like** to do this by way of a 'slang method call', something like this made up code...

```
# caller side
s.pd.shape;
s.pd.to_json("test.json");
s.pd.iloc[2] = 23;
^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^$
|  |       |
|  |       L a q// str I can put into eg. a custom Grammar
|  |
|  L general method name
|
L invocant

#callee side
method pd( ?? ) {
    my $called-as-str = self.^was-called-as;
    say $called-as-str;   #'pd.to_json("test.json")'
    ...
}
```

(HOW) can this be done in raku?

Since there are 422 calls to handle, of many arity patterns, answers that require the declaration of 422 methods and signatures in the called Class will be less attractive.

Comment: No time to write up a complete answer for this, but: return an object from `pd` that implements `FALLBACK` to cover the method-like cases, and you can implement `AT-POS` and use a `Proxy` to deal with providing different semantics for indexing and assignment respectively.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWorthington - the ```FALLBACK``` method is precisely what I am looking for and was missing. I will write an answer for any other viewers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per @jonathans comment, the raku [docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#Fallback_method) state:

> A method with the special name FALLBACK will be called when other
> means to resolve the name produce no result. The first argument holds
> the name and all following arguments are forwarded from the original
> call. Multi methods and sub-signatures are supported.

```
class Magic {
    method FALLBACK ($name, |c(Int, Str)) {
    put "$name called with parameters {c.raku}"  }
};
Magic.new.simsalabim(42, "answer");
 
# OUTPUT: «simsalabim called with parameters ⌈\(42, "answer")⌋␤»
```

So my code example would read:

```
# callee side
class Pd-Stub {
    method FALLBACK ($name, Str $arg-str ) {
        say "$name called with args: <<$arg-str>>"
    }
}

class Series { 
    has Pd-Stub $.pd 
}

my \s = Series.new;

# caller side
s.pd.shape;                 #shape called with args: <<>>        
s.pd.to_json("test.json");  #to_json called with args: <<test.json>>
s.pd.iloc[2] = 23;          #iloc called with args: <<>>

#iloc needs to use AT-POS and Proxy to handle subscript and assignment
```

Comment: :) DONRIP? DONRIP = Deletion Of Now Redundant Information Protocol. I deleted my prior comments that are no longer beneficial to later readers. I may later do another round of DONRIP. I invite you to consider doing likewise. The ideal outcome of DONRIP in a case like this is that you'd delete your comment, I'd delete this one, and later readers would be none the wiser. (But in this case I may leave this comment here so I can just write [DONRIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667086/get-method-called-as-str-in-the-callee/71668819?#comment126779099_71668819) in the future on later SOs.)

Comment: **I may DONRIP this comment later, but, to be clear, it might well be particularly perfect if you leave your comment in place this time to help later readers who I link here understand what I'm getting at.**